# No input file error from dev_appserver.py

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, cygwin

I am trying to create a helloworld GAE projects to use PHP to connect to a Google Cloud SQL database. I am following the steps found at:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

However, whenever I start the dev_appserver.py to test my helloworld.php I eventually get a permission denied error. I am running Cygwin (mintty) on a Win8 (64) machine. I have run `chmod -R 777 *` on a number of related directories like:
/usr/bin/

1. c:/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/
2. c:/Development/php/
3. c:/Development/Php Scripts/helloworld/

**Error**:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)

File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1232, in _loop_adjusting_instances
    self._adjust_instances()

File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1209, in _adjust_instances
    self._add_instance(permit_warmup=True)


 File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/server.py", line 1087, in _add_instance
    expect_ready_request=perform_warmup)

 File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 195, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)

 File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 138, in _check_environment
    env={})

File "/cygdrive/c/Development/appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/safe_subprocess.py", line 61, in start_process
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1248, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How can I determine what file the permission issue is with?

**EDIT**
There is no traceback from this new error (now that I am calling the actual exe):
`WARNING  2013-06-04 02:21:13,243 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-06-04 02:21:13,252 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51615
INFO     2013-06-04 02:21:13,261 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-06-04 02:21:13,324 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-06-04 02:21:13,553 php_runtime.py:199] The PHP runtime is not available because: No input file specified.`

Then when I go to `localhost:8080` I get this:
`The PHP interpreter specified with the --php_executable_path flag ("/cygdrive/c/Development/php/php-cgi.exe") is not compatible with the App Engine PHP development environment.

No input file specified.`

Comment: A quick&dirty way is to temporarily modify `safe_subprocess.py:61` to print the path or args before whatever call it's making. A cleaner way is to run it in the debugger and break at that line.

Comment: However, if you look a few levels up the stack chain, it seems pretty likely that it's `php_executable_path`. What did you specify in your yaml configs and/or `--php_executable-path` command line flags? Is it a Cygwin PHP interpreter, or a native Windows one? Can you run it from within a Cygwin shell?

Comment: @abarnert app.yaml is  `application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php`

Comment: @abarnert my command is  ` appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/cygdrive/c/Development/php/ /cygdrive/c/Development/PhpScripts/helloworld/`

Comment: @menting311, try changing the `php_executable_path` to be the binary for php, not the directory.  Something like `--php_executable_path=/cygdrive/c/Development/php/bin/php`, or wherever it is on your system.

Comment: @kgraney According to the GAE docs for this project I am supposed to use the php-cgi binary. But when I give the command the full path to php-cgi.exe I get a different error   `ERROR    2013-06-04 02:21:13,553 php_runtime.py:199] The PHP runtime is not available because: No input file specified.`

Comment: @kgraney  This is the flag I am using (per the Google tutorial) for my path   `--php_executable_path=/cygdrive/c/Development/php/php-cgi.exe`

Comment: OK, we've fixed your initial problem, now you have a completely different error. But we still only have the traceback to your original problem, which doesn't do any good. Either edit this question to show the new traceback, or post it elsewhere, or create a new question. (Do not remove the original question and traceback.)

Comment: @abarnert  I tried adding a print statement near this line and ended up causing the .py file to no longer run.  There is a debug line right near the error that probably has what I need. How do I run the python script to output debug info?  Line 60 from `safe_subprocess.py:` ` logging.debug('Starting process %r with input=%r, env=%r, cwd=%r',
                  args, input_string, env, cwd)`

Comment: @abarnert OK, I edited the question. The error from going to `localhost:8080` in my browser is very odd being that this `php-cgi` is what Goolge itself says to use.

Comment: @menting311: Does Google really say to use the native-Windows version of `php-cgi` that you're using with the cygwin GAE? If so, where? (And where _did_ you get that `php-cgi`?)

Comment: @menting311: If you just mean they said to put the path to `php-cgi` (in "Testing" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld))—well, yeah, of course they did. But that doesn't mean anything that happens to be named `php-cgi` will work. The error you get specifically says that "The PHP interpreter specified … is not compatible with the App Engine PHP development environment".

Comment: @abarnert  See the [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld)   -  Under the `Testing Your Application`

Comment: @abarnert  Well I did a search of my laptop and this is the only file called `php-cgi`  I also tried `php.exe` (same directory as the cgi version) and that gives yet a different error

Comment: Let's step back a second. Why are you using a cygwin Python build instead of a native Windows one in the first place? And, if you have a good answer for that, why are you using a native GAE and PHP with that cygwin Python? Even if you have a good reason for all of that in production, you ought to at least work through the tutorial doing things the easy way before going out of your way to make things hard for yourself.

Comment: @abarnert I did download the Python 2.7 exactly as the tutorial says. However, when the tutorial says to test the application it just gives the command to run, it doesn't say how/where to run it. I just opened up cygwin as it is what I usually use as a command line tool on Windows.  So, since I do have the Python 2.7 files on my machine, how should I run the command?  Also, thankyou for the help.

Comment: @menting311: You can run a native Python from inside `cygwin`. You can do this either by making sure `C:\Python27\bin` or whatever is higher on your `PATH` than `/usr/bin`, or by just explicitly running `C:\Python27\bin\python` instead of `python`. (This is all basic POSIX/bash stuff; if you don't understand it, I'm not sure why you're using cygwin in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your command line:

```
appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/cygdrive/c/Development/php/ /cygdrive/c/Development/PhpScripts/helloworld/
```

Your `php_executable_path` is not an executable, but a directory. So, GAE tries to run `/cygdrive/c/Development/php/` as if it were a program, and gets an `EACCES` ("permission denied"), exactly as it should.

The fix is to pass `/cygdrive/c/Development/php/php.exe` (or whatever it's called) instead.

---

I believe your new problem is exactly what I mentioned in an early comment, and in the earlier version of this answer: You're mixing cygwin and native code in ways that don't work.

In particular, it looks like you're running a native Windows version of GAE in a cygwin Python interpreter, and then pointing it at a native Windows `php-cgi` interpreter. It's hard to guess exactly which one of these multiple mismatches is to blame, but it's quite likely that one of them is. So, either:

- Use a native Windows Python, or
- Use a cygwin/POSIX GAE and a cygwin PHP interpreter.

Comment: Can you suggest a native Windows Python command line environment?

Comment: @menting311: Yes. Go to http://python.org, and click the link to download the Python installer for Windows. The link from the GAE instructions would also work (since it points to the same page).

Comment: Or, even simpler… doesn't the Windows GAE SDK come with its own embedded Python interpreter, and a launcher that uses it, so as long as you don't go out of your way to explicitly run `dev_appserver.py` under a different Python?

Comment: If it does, Google doesn't explicitly say how to use it. Or if it did, I completely missed it.

Comment: Just to be clear...the php-cgi.exe php interpreter I am giving the command is the one from the Python 2.7 download right from the GAE tutorial.

Comment: and that is meant to run under a native windows python (see download at python.org) and not for python under cygwin

Comment: @TimHoffman: Actually, I think GAE for Windows may include a complete native windows Python 2.7, and it's meant to run under _that_. But either way, your larger point is still right on target. The problem is like something to do with using a cygwin Python (possibly in particular using a Python where "native path" means "POSIX path" instead of "Windows path").